# Suppose that events $A$, $B$ and $C$ satisfy $P(A \cap B \cap C) = 0$ and each of them has probability not smaller than $\frac{2}{3}$. Find $P(A)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inclusion-exclusion

> Suppose that events $A$, $B$, and $C$ satisfy $P(A \cap B \cap C) = 0$ and each of them has probability not smaller than $\dfrac{2}{3}$. Find $P(A)$.

I don't understand this statement:

> $A \cap B$, $B \cap C$ and $C \cap A$ are (pairwise) disjoint events. Therefore, the sum of their probabilities is the probability of their union which cannot be greater than $1$.

Why is the sum of the probability of these three pairwise disjoint events $\leq 1$? shouldn't the probability of their union be $0$ such that the sum of their probabilities is not greater than zero? Please explain thanks.

> Solution: From the inclusion-exclusion formula
>   $1 \geq P(A \cup B \cup C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) − P(A \cap B) − P(B \cap C) − P(C \cap A)$, hence $P(A \cap B) + P(B \cap C) + P(C \cap A) \geq 1$. But $A \cap B$, $B \cap C$ and $C \cap A$ are (pairwise) disjoint events. Therefore the sum of their probabilities is the probability of their union which cannot be greater than $1$. This means that we have equality everywhere, in particular, $P(A) = \dfrac{2}{3}$.

Comment: @an4s I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

$P(A\cap B)=P(A\cap B \cap C^{c})$ because $P(A\cap B \cap C)=0$. So $P(A\cap B) \leq P(C^{c})=1-P(C) \leq 1/3$. Hence $P(A)=P(A \cap B)+P(A \cap B^{c}) \leq 1/3 + P(A \cap B^{c}) \leq 1/3 +(1-P(B)) \leq 1/3+1/3=2/3$. Hence $P(A)\leq 2/3$ and $P(A) \geq 2/3$ so $P(A)=2/3$.

Comment: i dont understand the intuition behind "A∩B, B∩C and C∩A are (pairwise) disjoint events. Therefore, the sum of their probabilities is the probability of their union which cannot be greater than 1." even though your maht proof is very well done thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If any two of $A \cap B, B\cap C, A \cap C$ happen, then $A \cap B \cap C$ happens and we have been told it cannot, so at most one of them happens.  This means they are pairwise disjoint.

Comment: why is their probability sum not greater than one though?

Comment: sorry my phrasing of the question is weird but i intended to ask why is the sum of probability of these three pairwise dijsoint events <=1?

Comment: The probability of the union of disjoint events is the sum of the probabilities of the individual events.  All probabilities are less than or equal to $1$.

Comment: but the union of individual events (aka disjoint events) here should be zero, no?

Comment: A∩BUB∩CUA∩C does not equal to A∩B∩C? how would i simplify A∩BUB∩CUA∩C then out of curiosity?

Comment: You should use parentheses in an expression like that.  No, $(A \cap B)\cup (B \cap C) \cup (A \cap C) \neq A \cap B \cap C$.  Let $A=\{0,1\}, B=\{0,2\}, C=\{1,2\}.  (A \cap B)\cup (B \cap C) \cup (A \cap C)=\{0,1,2\}, A \cap B \cap C=\emptyset$

Answer (score -1):

Simpler:

Consider the complements $A'$, $B'$ and $C'$, of $A$, $B$ and $C$, then $P(A'\cup B'\cup C')=1$ while $P(A')\leqslant\frac13$, $P(B')\leqslant\frac13$, and $P(C')\leqslant\frac13$ since $P(A)\geqslant\frac23$, $P(B)\geqslant\frac23$, and $P(C)\geqslant\frac23$.

Since $P(A'\cup B'\cup C')\leqslant P(A')+P(B')+P(C')$, this implies that $P(A')=P(B')=P(C')=\frac13$.

In particular, $P(A)=\frac23$.

Comment: Interesting (that is, stinking) silent downvotes...